# Bootstrap alert not showing after php-ajax form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to show alert when the user submits the form, whether it's a success or not. The script is working fine in submitting the data but the alert is not showing.The code is-

IMPORTANT- The form is in bootstrap modal.

HTML is:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <form id="inquiry-form" method="post" action="inq.php" role="form">
         <div class="messages"></div>
         <div class="controls">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Name">Name</label>
                 <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Name" required="required" data-error="Name is required."/>
                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

My php Script is:

```
try
{
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO wig (fname, lname, email,msg)
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email','$msg')");



$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
$responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $encoded;
}
else {
echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

And the jquery to handle the form submission is:

```
$(function () {

$('#inquiry-form').validator();

$('#inquiry-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "inq.php";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data)
            {
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;

                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable fade in role=alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' + messageText + '</div>';
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    $('#inquiry-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    $('#inquiry-form')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
})
});
```

Comment: did you try to debug the `success`function of the ajax?

Comment: yup @cmnardi , Actually it's working fine without modal but in mdal it is not working.

Comment: Does AJAX work at all?

Comment: yup @xpuc7o , the insertion is going on, but the alert is not showing.

Comment: You didnt close the `class="alert` part right! `role=alert` is currently in the class attribute -- always use the dev.console F12 in Browser!

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions after the correction also, it is not working

Comment: Nope! or you have drop the wrong code here `'<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable fade in role=alert">` How can this be right?

Comment: Right is: `'<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable fade in"  role="alert">` --see the last part

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions after the correction also, it is not working

Comment: You have to use the debug console!!  Press F12 and cklick on `console` tab, there are the javascript errors. also use `console.log(data)` in your success function, may you find the bug

Comment: In the `console` under Network, you can also see what was returned from your ajax call.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions There are no bugs in the console

Comment: Sry, but from here i cant really help, it could be everything. But if you test step by step your js code (for syntax errors, logic errors) and ensure that the ajax response is set up right, you can find the buggy part i thing. Whatever, the `console` for debugging is your best tool:)

Comment: Last note: Maybe you cant use Alerts in Modal !? Look here:http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions well thanks for the ajax response idea, the code worked. Just logical error in php script. And you can use alerts in modals. ;)

Comment: Fine :-) I keep that `alerts in modals` in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `die` to your php script like so:

```
    echo $encoded;   
}else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
die();
```